# HelloFacebookSample project, strange behaviour on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm running through the sample project provided with the Facebook SDK and I'm encountering something that's a little weird.

The general idea for the sample project is: You can post via the Facebook app on your phone

- if that's not available but iOS 6 integration is, you can post via that.
- If that's not available the last resort is to post via the Facebook website.

Now, on the simulator, which doesn't have the Facebook app, but is iOS 6.1, it allows the Facebook integration via iOS6. The modal view controller pops up, but because I'm not logged in, it asks me to do so via the iPhone settings. That's the response I want.

However, on my development 3GS, running 6.1.3, the `[FBDialogs canPresentOSIntegratedShareDialogWithSession:nil];` doesn't seem to detect that the iPhone has iOS 6 Facebook integration, but just isn't logged in. Therefore the popup window for Facebook doesn't appear and doesn't ask me to log in.

Any one know why?

Comment: FB provides their iOS source code... have you tried to attach it and debug?